# how to sort parameters with Jenkins parametrized job?

Tags: jenkins

**Problem:**

A Jenkins job is starting to have a lot of parameter (over 20).

Is there a way to group them, have title, etc...?

I looked up and found none.

Comment: If you've got over 20 parameters for a Jenkins job, I would look at the design of the job and possibly break it up into smaller jobs.  Twenty parameters seems pretty excessive.

Comment: thanks a lot!! However where I am the criteria is reduce job numbers... over variables quantity (I had to fuse 3 jobs, that is how I ended up with 20)

Comment: jenkins defined parameters are of Key value pair , Now what is the main issue you facing with more parameters , is it related to naming convention ?

Comment: just sorting, it's a task we will need to build often, but it's just messy with so many parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of sorting parameters automatically that I'm aware of. You can arrange them via Drag&Drop in your project's config manually, of course.

You can group them using the [Parameter Separator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameter+Separator+Plugin):

*Meta Data* → [✔] *This build is parameterized* → *Add Parameter* → *Parameter Separator*

Comment: Found it, thanks : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameter+Separator+Plugin